# Proving existence of a convex set given a convex funtion

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, convex-analysis

I want to show that if $$f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$$ is a convex function, then the set $$C=\{\ x\in \Bbb R^n : f(x) \le c\ \}$$ is a convex set.

My intuition tells me to do the following: Let $x_1, x_2 \in C$, then from here we know that $f(x_1)<C$ and $f(x_2)<C$. Now I want to kinda dorm the definition of the convex function by defining an $x=\lambda x_1 + (1 - \lambda)x_2$ for some $\lambda\in[0,1]$. From here I think I can finish it.

My question stems from the first part of my "proof". Can I just start right off the bat like that and pull elements out of the set? Do I have to show my "formulation" of the set or of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can pull $x_1,x_2\in C$ out without saying anything else.  And yes, as $f$ is convex, you know that it satisfies the inequality convex functions satisfy.

This is the strength of abstract proofs - we specifically *don't* want to specify specific functions or sets.  By not specifying an explicit function or set, this now holds for **all** convex functions $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ and **all** corresponding sets $C = \{x\in\mathbb R^n\mid f(x)\leq c\}$.

Comment: Right, I guess I was more so concerned that I was pulling results from something I am trying to conclude on... But in this case, for abstract prrofs, this is what we do?

Comment: @10101088101010 Yes, this is what we do.  You're right to be worried about pulling results from something we construct.  The main worry you should have is that it's possible that for given $c\in\mathbb R$, that $C$ is empty (as an example, $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ where $f(x) = 0$ will mean $C$ is empty when $c<0$, even though $f$ is convex).  It may be the case that you need a separate proof for when $C$ is empty.  But, the set $\{x\in\mathbb R^n\mid f(x)\leq c\}$ exists for all $c$ and all functions $f$.  It might be empty, it might be a single point, it might be all of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Provided you deal with all possible forms $C$ can take, the proof should be valid in every situation.